# Request.Files is empty when using input type file with ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload

When posting back to my controller my model is populated with correct values and my string field has the file name, but Request.Files is empty.

My input at the view is:

```
<input id="SitePlan" name="SitePlan" type="file" value="<%= Html.Encode(Model.SitePlan) %>" />
```

My form tag begins with:

```
 <% using (Html.BeginForm(new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

Is there anything else I need to set to send the field back to the controller?

Comment: What is in Model.SitePlan? I believe most browsers will not allow you to assign a default value to an <input type="file" />, but I am not sure if this is related to the problem you are facing.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but my using statement looks like the answer:
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadPatientFiles", "Wizard", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "uploadForm", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
Any other reasons this could be happening?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have a look at the the <form> tag that is rendered. There is no Html.BeginForm declaration that just takes in the htmlAttributes that you are using. In fact, it uses the html attributes as routeValues. Try this...

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("actionName", "controllerName", FormMethod.Post, 
   new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) { %>
```